# Adjust p.value for each term from list of ANOVA results/tidy DF's

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse, anova, p-value

I have a data with 2 independent variables and a thousands of dependent variables. I've performed multiple two-way ANOVA tests a now I have a list containing result for each dependent variable. Let's say that the list looks like this (example data):

```
> l
$a
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  term         df sumsq meansq statistic   p.value
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Species       2  63.2 31.6        119.  1.67e-31
2 Residuals   147  39.0  0.265       NA  NA

$b
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  term         df sumsq  meansq statistic   p.value
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Species       2 437.  219.        1180.  2.86e-91
2 Residuals   147  27.2   0.185       NA  NA
```

Now I would like to use the `p.adjust` method for each term. So what I want to do is to retrieve `p.value` for `Species`, `...`, `Residuals` from all dataframes in this list, then use the `p.adjust` on a vector of p.values from specific term and add each adjusted p.value to respective dataframe (to new column in respective term). Is there any way to do this in a simple (tidyverse?) way? Key here is to use the `p.adjust` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find an answer to this. Although the method is not a "tidyverse" way. Let data look like this:

```
> a = aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
> b = aov(Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
> l = list(a = broom::tidy(a), b = broom::tidy(b))
> n_terms = nrow(l[[1]])
> n_terms
[1] 2
> for(i in seq_along(l)){
+   l[[i]]$q.value = 0
+ }
> l
$a
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  term         df sumsq meansq statistic   p.value q.value
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Species       2  63.2 31.6        119.  1.67e-31       0
2 Residuals   147  39.0  0.265       NA  NA              0

$b
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  term         df sumsq  meansq statistic   p.value q.value
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Species       2 437.  219.        1180.  2.86e-91       0
2 Residuals   147  27.2   0.185       NA  NA              0
```

The we can create a for loop for each term. In loop we retrieve each p.value for given term using `purrr::map_dbl`. After that we adjust the vector of pvalues using `p.adjust` method using desired method. Next step is to loop over every old q.value for a given term and set it to previously calculated value.

```
> for(term in 1:n_terms){
+   p.vals = purrr::map_dbl(l, ~.x[term, ]$p.value)
+   adjusted = as.vector(p.adjust(p.vals, method = "BY"))
+   for(i in seq_along(adjusted)){
+     l[[i]]$q.value[term] = adjusted[i]
+   }
+ }
> l
$a
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  term         df sumsq meansq statistic   p.value   q.value
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Species       2  63.2 31.6        119.  1.67e-31  2.50e-31
2 Residuals   147  39.0  0.265       NA  NA        NA       

$b
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  term         df sumsq  meansq statistic   p.value   q.value
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Species       2 437.  219.        1180.  2.86e-91  8.57e-91
2 Residuals   147  27.2   0.185       NA  NA        NA
```